# How can I have the average from multiple column to put in the line graph with SD?

Tags: ggplot2, average

[enter link description here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AaPmG2vaN66DMkbP7w_Sl1ZDTMesMVxd/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=113128344399422584227&rtpof=true&sd=true)

My data is like this (in the link) I need to calculate the average value from A,B, and C and so on. In that case, how can I calculate the average for the given data and plot all in  a single graph using line graph? Also, in this case, do I need to put the SD as well?

My data is like this. I need to calculate the average value from A,B, and C and so on. In that case, how can I calculate the average for the given data and plot all in  a single graph using line graph? Also, in this case, do I need to put the SD as well?

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach your data is as follows. Let's say your dataframe, which we'll call `df`, has a first column of labels (we'll rename yours as `conc`, in keeping with R variable name conventions), and then columns 2:16 contain your data. Then we can add columns with mean and standard deviation as follows:

```
df$mean <- apply(df[,2:16], 1, mean)
df$sd <- apply(df[,2:16], 1, sd)
```

We can then graph the means with `geom_line`, and add the SDs as error bars with `geom_errorbar`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=conc, y=mean)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin= mean - sd, ymax= mean + sd))
```

[image]

Or, if you really want to plot every column of data separately, and also add a line for mean -/+ SD, you can use the `dplyr` function `pivot_longer` to remodel your data into "tidy" format, and then plot from the tidy data plus the updated `df` we created above:

```
df_tidy <- pivot_longer(df[1:16], cols=-conc, names_to='name', values_to='value')
ggplot(df_tidy, aes(x=conc, y=value, col=name)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(data=df, aes(x=conc, y=mean), col='red', lwd=1) +
  geom_errorbar(data=df, aes(x=conc, y=mean, ymin=mean - sd, ymax=mean + sd), col='red', lwd=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Here, A, B, and C are different column,s and "One" is the average value of this three column. Same goes for Two and Three.  Since, I have calculated the "One" from A, B and C, I need to have the SD for this and need to plot it. The same thing is for Two and Three.

Comment: Lol okay - I would suggest removing the One, Two and Three columns from your df, using `mutate` to calculate the mean and SD for each of the groups of columns that you care about, then using `pivot_longer` and code similar to what I've done above, to get your plot. It should work fine.

Comment: d <- readxl::read_excel("Bioassay.xlsx") |>
    pivot_longer(
        cols = c(one, two, three, four),
        names_to = "Fraction", values_to = "Absorbance"
    ) |>
    mutate(
        Fraction = factor(Fraction, levels = c("one", "two", "three", "four"))
    )


d |> ggplot(aes(Concentration, Absorbance, color = Fraction)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line() +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(panel.grid = element_blank()) +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, NA), expand = c(0, 0))

Comment: I did use this one. Till this part, everything is okay. But the problem is with the SD. I mean for "one", there is SD, same goes for "two", "three",  and "four". So, how can I put these four different SD for four different lines?